# Hidden attribute in Tailwindcss

Tags: html, css, frontend, tailwind-css, responsive

I tried adding a `hidden` attribute to some contents in the navbar using TailwindCSS. In the tag I used `hidden md:block` where the content suppose to be displayed when the screen size gets to `768px and above`. but that doesn't work. **Rather the content just stayed hidden.** How do I resolve this?

I tried using visibility but it doesn't work like I want it to. The content still takes up that space it's just not visible and I think using `hidden` would be a better solution.

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  mode: "jit",
  content: ["./public/index.html"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        main: "#ADEFD1",
        darkBlue: "#00203F",
        accent: "#EFADCB",
        color: "rgb(205,205,205)",
      },
      fontFamily: {
        Electrolize: ["Electrolize"],
      },
      dropShadow: {
        shadow1: "3px 5px 8px rgb(173,239,209, 1)",
      },
      keyframes: {
        wiggle: {
          "0%": { transform: "translate(-25%)" },
          "50%": { transform: "translate(25%)" },
          "100%": { transform: "translate(-25%)" },
        },
        wiggle1: {
          "0%": { transform: "translate(-25%)" },
          "50%": { transform: "translate(25%)" },
          "100%": { transform: "translate(-25%)" },
        },
        wiggle2: {
          "0%": { transform: "translate(-25%)" },
          "50%": { transform: "translate(25%)" },
          "100%": { transform: "translate(-25%)" },
        },
        rotate: {
          "0%": { transform: "rotate(0deg)" },
          "25%": { transform: "rotate(-30deg)" },
          "75%": { transform: "rotate( 30deg)" },
          "100%": { transform: "rotate(0deg)" },
        },
        scaleIt: {
          0: { transform: "scaleX(0%)" },
          100: { transform: "scaleX(100%)" },
        },
        flip: {
          from: {
            transform: "rotateX(-75deg)",
            opacity: ".1",
          },
          to: { transform: "rotateX(0deg)", opacity: "1" },
        },
        slideRight: {
          from: {
            transform: "translateX(-30%)",
            opacity: "0",
          },
          to: {
            transform: "translateX(0%)",
            opacity: "1",
          },
        },
        slideLeft: {
          from: {
            transform: "translateX(30%)",
            opacity: "0",
          },
          to: {
            transform: "translateX(0%)",
            opacity: "1",
          },
        },
        dropIn: {
          from: {
            transform: "translateY(-60%)",
            opacity: "0",
          },
          to: {
            transform: "translateY(0%)",
            opacity: "1",
          },
        },
        moveUp: {
          from: {
            transform: "translateY(60%)",
            opacity: "0",
          },
          to: {
            transform: "translateY(0%)",
            opacity: "1",
          },
        },
        flipSide: {
          from: {
            transform: "rotateY(80deg)",
            opacity: "0",
          },
          to: {
            transform: "rotateY(0deg)",
            opacity: "1",
          },
        },
      },

      animation: {
        wiggle: "wiggle 7s ease-in-out infinite",
        wiggle1: " wiggle1 9s ease-in-out infinite",
        wiggle2: " wiggle2 8s ease-in-out infinite",
        rotate: "rotate 5s ease-in-out infinite",
        scaleIt: "scaleIt 10s ease-in-out ",
        flip: "flip 1s ease-in-out forwards",
        slideLeft: "slideLeft 1s ease-in-out forwards",
        slideRight: "slideRight 1s ease-in-out forwards",
        dropIn: "dropIn 1s ease-in-out forwards",
        flipSide: "flipSide 2s ease-in-out forwards",
        moveUp: "moveUp 3s ease-in-out 3s forwards",
      },
      backgroundImage: {
        curve1: "url('./public/images/curve_left.png')",
      },
      dropShadow: {
        "3xl": "0 5px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5)",
        "4xl": ["0 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.5)", "0 -1px 4px rgba(0,0,0, .3)"],
      },
      screens: {
        break2: "850px",
        break1: "950px",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [require("@kamona/tailwindcss-perspective")],
};
```

This is how my tailwind config looks like

Comment: `hidden md:block` should work fine, to get the element displayed for >768px. If I add the `md:block` class to the first, hidden element in the example under https://tailwindcss.com/docs/display#hidden via browser dev tools, it works exactly as expected. Please provide a proper [mre] of your issue.

Comment: This code is the same as yours and it works find, post you tailwind config and let us see if there is an isue there

https://play.tailwindcss.com/XVJoMk6Tts

Comment: How do I post my tailwind config file?

Comment: I have done that @Sarkar

Comment: You changed the screens, i think that's the issue, the correct class is now `break1:block`, i would suggest to keep the screen names like xs/sm/md/lg/xl etc, it's less confusing and actually allow you to copy pastes classes from the internet, witthout having to rename the screens.

Comment: Yes, I have corrected that but still the issue persist

Comment: @VictorWinner what is the file called that you are currently editing?